# Can I make this function cleaner by using not forEach() but .reduce() please?

Tags: javascript, foreach, reduce

> Can I make this function cleaner by using not forEach() but .reduce()
> please?

```
const post = [
  {
    id: "1",
    dateOfPost: "15.10.2020",
    postTitle: "...",
    postText: "...",
    },
    comments: [
      {
        id: "1",
        dateOfComment: "15.10.2020",
        gravatar: "...",
        nicName: "...",
        commentText: "...",
        starRating: 3,
        likeCount: 8,
        dislikeCount: 1
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        dateOfComment: "15.10.2020",
        gravatar: "...",
        nicName: "...",
        commentText: "...",
        starRating: 5,
        likeCount: 1,
        dislikeCount: 1
      },
    ]
  }
];

const postComments = post[0].comments;
const starRatingAverage = () => {
  let starRatingAVG = 0;
  postComments.forEach(comment => {
    starRatingAVG = starRatingAVG + comment.starRating
  })
  return starRatingAVG = starRatingAVG / postComments.length;
}
```

> I'm just a beginner and I'm training to do things right. So I will be
> grateful for all your help. Thanks.

Comment: Your input array is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of `starRating` using `Array.reduce` and map the average to the each element of `posts` using `Array.map`.

```js
const post = [{
  id: "1",
  dateOfPost: "15.10.2020",
  postTitle: "...",
  postText: "...",
  comments: [{
      id: "1",
      dateOfComment: "15.10.2020",
      gravatar: "...",
      nicName: "...",
      commentText: "...",
      starRating: 3,
      likeCount: 8,
      dislikeCount: 1
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      dateOfComment: "15.10.2020",
      gravatar: "...",
      nicName: "...",
      commentText: "...",
      starRating: 5,
      likeCount: 1,
      dislikeCount: 1
    },
  ]
}];

const output = post.map(({ comments }) => (comments.length > 0 ? comments.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.starRating, 0) / comments.length : 0));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Replace this:

```
  let starRatingAVG = 0;
  postComments.forEach(comment => {
    starRatingAVG = starRatingAVG + comment.starRating
  })
```

With this:

```
  let starRatingAVG = postComments.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x.starRating, 0);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, if you fix your usage of `reduce`. If `.reduce()` is called without a second argument, it starts at the second element of the array and `acc` is the first element. So the summation will not work.

Comment: Whoops, thanks, fixed.